# passing dynamic parameter in curl from seperate file in bash shell

Tags: json, forms, bash, curl, parameters

In a bash script i want to get date dynamically and send it along with the 
curl call.

i have got the date from the user in the bash script
and in the script am making the below curl call. am already passing the request params using a separate file as below. How do i pass the date?
 i have tried like $date, but it is not working, even tried "'$date'".

The below is my curl call:

```
curl -O -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@formparams.json --url http://test.com
```

Contents of form params json: it has more than 10 params for simplicity iam including only two

```
{"params":"{"HOSTS:":"1",date=$date}}
```

in the above i have added date.

But the date is not replaced.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a here document instead of a separate file for the parameters. Inside the here document, you can run the `date` command in a command substitution to provide the correct date when the document is read.

```
curl -O -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@- --url http://test.com <<EOF
{"params":"{"HOSTS:":"1", "date": "$(date)"}}
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

use this json for pass dynamic parameter

```
{"params":"{"HOSTS:":"1",date="'$date'"}}
```